# Variable argument function: Bad access with va_arg at iOS arm64

Tags: c++, ios, unity-game-engine

I have a function like this:

```
typedef long long myint64;

typedef enum {
    INT32_FIELD,
    CHARP_FIELD,
    INT64_FIELD,
} InfoType;

int32_t ReadInfo(void *handle, InfoType info, ...)
{
    va_list arg;
    va_start(arg, info);
    void *argPtr = va_arg(arg, void*);
    va_end(arg);

    int32_t ret = 0;
    int32_t *paramInt = NULL;
    char **paramCharp = NULL;
    myint64 *paramInt64 = NULL;

    switch (info) {
    case INT32_FIELD:
        paramInt = static_cast<int32_t*>(argPtr);
        *paramInt = functionWhichReturnsInt32();
        break;
    case CHARP_FIELD:
        paramCharp = static_cast<char**>(argPtr);
        *paramCharp = functionWhichReturnsCharPtr();
        break;
    case INT64_FIELD:
        paramInt64 = static_cast<myint64*>(argPtr);
        *paramInt64 = functionWhichReturnsInt64();
        break;
     default:
        ret = -1;
        break;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Call this function like this from separated c file. This file does not include definition of ReadInfo function:

```
extern "C" {int32_t CDECL ReadInfo(intptr_t, int32_t, int32_t*);}

int32_t readInt()
{
    int32_t value = 0;
    int32_t *ptr = &value;
    ReadInfo(handle, INT32_FIELD, ptr);
    return value;
}
```

This call fails only under iOS arm64. arm7s and win32 work fine with this call. (Yes, our only 64 bit target platform is iOS arm64.)
In debugger I found that address of ptr in readInt function is different from what I got with:
    void *argPtr = va_arg(arg, void*);

Am I working wrong with arg_list?

P.S. It is not a plain Objective C application. It is part of native Unity plugin. But in iOS Unity code is just transformed into Objective C/C++ from C#. That is why you can see second declaration:

```
extern "C" {int32_t CDECL ReadInfo(intptr_t, int32_t, int32_t*);}
```

Comment: Are enums 32bit on arm64/ios? If that's not the case, the extern decleration is wrong.

Comment: @dognotdog: _enum-constants_ in C are of type `int`. `enum`s themselves are thus not "larger" than `int`.

Comment: @Olaf, the compiler is free to choose an integer type, it doesn't have to be `int`. I am not sure what clang does for arm64/ios, a simple `assert(sizeof(InfoType) == sizeof(int32_t))` could clear it up though.

Comment: @dognotdog: What maybe wrong in extern declaration?

Comment: @JohnGreen, see my comment above, just the question about `sizeof(InfoType) == sizeof(int32_t)` being true on arm64?

Comment: @dognotdog: The compiler is free to choose a "smaller" type which can hold all listed values, but the max. type is `int` (which makes sense, as the constants are always `int`). Please clarify where I stated something different in my comment! And the choice of the types is a matter of the ABI/PCS, not just the compiler. Not sure if Apple uses AAPCS, but that one is free for download; you might want to read it.

Comment: @dognotdog:  I just added line of code `if (sizeof(InfoType) != sizeof(int32_t)) return -1;` But the size of InfoType is equal with the side of int32_t. Maybe you have any other ideas?

Comment: @JohnGreen Does your compiler support `static_assert`?  If so, then this line `static_assert(sizeof(InfoType) == sizeof(int32_t));` is much better than a line of code at runtime, and checking a return value.  If they are truly equal, then your program will compile, if not, then compilation will stop with an error.  If your compiler doesn't support `static_assert`, then there are ways of emulating it at *compile-time*, and not make it a runtime assert.  You want to make sure that the program you're creating is valid, and compile time is the earliest way to do this check.

Comment: @Olaf, on 64bit ios, `int` is 32bit, `long` is 64, and if the enum contains a value that does not fit in 32 bits, the compiler WILL make it a 64bit enum.

Comment: @dognotdog: No, it would be undefined behaviour. But where is a 64 bit enum-constant? Do I overlook another `enum` than `InfoType`?

Comment: @Olaf it is undefined in the C standard (in the sense that the compiler may choose the smallest type), but that's what clang does when you compile for 64bit ios, I just tried it. It is also what gcc does, if memory serves me right. The enum is 32bit unless it contains a value that necessitates it being larger, special compiler flags notwithstanding. EDIT: values of constants in InfoType aren't shown in code snippet, hence wanting to make sure.

Comment: Disable compiler extensions and enable all warnings.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I did a workaround. I adding answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's not an issue of IL2CPP but an issue of iOS, or maybe the compiler.

The following code could reproduce the issue even on the latest Xcode (10.1) and iOS (12.1)

```
typedef int __cdecl (*PInvokeFunc) (const char*, int);

int test()
{
    PInvokeFunc fp = (PInvokeFunc)printf;
    fp("Hello World: %d", 10);
    return 0;
}
```

The expected output is: `Hello World: 10` but it will give `Hello World: ??? (Random number)` on iOS however.

I tried the same code on macOS and Linux and both of them work well.

I'm not sure if it relates to the Apple document or not:

> Variadic Functions
>   The iOS ABI for functions that take a variable number of arguments is entirely different from the generic version.
>
> Stages A and B of the generic procedure call standard are performed as usual—in particular, even variadic aggregates larger than 16 bytes are passed via a reference to temporary memory allocated by the caller. After that, the fixed arguments are allocated to registers and stack slots as usual in iOS.
>
> The NSRN is then rounded up to the next multiple of 8 bytes, and each variadic argument is assigned to the appropriate number of 8-byte stack slots.
>
> The C language requires arguments smaller than int to be promoted before a call, but beyond that, unused bytes on the stack are not specified by this ABI.
>
> As a result of this change, the type va_list is an alias for char * rather than for the struct type specified in the generic PCS. It is also not in the std namespace when compiling C++ code.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iPhoneOSABIReference/Articles/ARM64FunctionCallingConventions.html

---

Updates:

The reply for Apple engineer:

> Casting function pointers to add a different calling convention doesn’t change how the callee is represented, it only changes how the caller performs its call. printf already has a calling convention, and what you’re doing might happen to work for some combinations on some platforms, while not working on others. You want to declare a wrapper function instead, which has the desired calling convention, and which calls the function you want. You’ll need to marshal the arguments manually.

That is to say the variadic function can't be direct p/invoke unless IL2CPP generate wrapper function for it. Only a function pointer is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

The reason of this problem was in IL2CPP, which generates calls of function with variable argument. And it does not use my types like InfoType, myint64. It uses platform specific types for info variable. And size maybe different I guess.

I just add 3 new function for Unity API:

```
int32_t ReadInfoInt(void *handle, InfoType info, int *ret);
int32_t ReadInfoInt64(void *handle, InfoType info, myint64 *ret);
int32_t ReadInfoStr(void *handle, InfoType info, char **ret);
```

In this function I just call ReadInfo.

It is workaround 100%, but it is better then fight with IL2CPP.

Comment: I'm interested to know how IL2CPP comes into the mix here. Can you provide more details (maybe on the Unity forums)? If there is something we can do so that you don't have to fight IL2CPP, we'll try to fix it.

Comment: @JoshPeterson I add my investigation in my comment. How about if the IL2CPP use a varying argument function pointer instead of an explicit one?

Comment: @jayatubi Unfortunately IL2CPP cannot emit variadic arguments here. In order to match the accepted behavior of other .NET runtimes, it must emit marshaling code directly as specified via extern statements in C#.

Comment: @JoshPeterson That is sad and means any native variadic arguments function can't work in an iOS IL2CPP build because the compiler can't handle the function pointer well for now.

Comment: @JoshPeterson How about if the IL2CPP could auto generate some type explicit wrapper functions for the variadic arguments function? So that could be a workaround for iOS.

Comment: @jayatubi Unfortunately variadic functions are not part of the p/invoke specification, so IL2CPP cannot generate them.